# Can someone help me understand what this address is? has a lot of weird transactions. I am trying to track a scammer

Tags: wallets, addresses, exchanges

How can I find out a specific address that belongs to which exchange?  I am trying to track a scammer. my tokens were stolen and transferred to this address: 0xf629cbd94d3791c9250152bd8dfbdf380e2a3b9c
can anybody help please?
Thank you and kind regards

Answer (score 1):

sorry that this happened to you first of all.

Usually exchanges will be listed like 'Binance 3' or 'Coinbase 2' etc. You can see different types of transactions by filtering them out on the view options bar on the right.

I would recommend getting a Trezor or a Ledger to protect yourself in the future: https://support.mycrypto.com/staying-safe/hardware-wallet-recommendations